# Subspaces of Vector Spaces Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image: Link to original problem]

I am a little confused on where to start here. I know that I need to somehow prove that U3 is contained in U2 and I know that the fact they are subspaces is likely important (use additive identity). I just can't put all the pieces together.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the dimensions  of $U+V,U,V,U\cap V$ as vector spaces? That is a standard exercise : $\dim U + \dim V = \dim (U+V) + \dim(U \cap V)$. Try to see how the above follows from this statement.

Comment: Do you have access to the definition of dimension? Are you assured if V is finite dimensional? This may be a case where the class has gotten to that concept and so it is not allowed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional makes this elegant, but it's not a necessary assumption. We start by assuming $v \in U_3$, with a view to showing that $v \in U_2$. Since $0 \in U_1$, we have
$$v = 0 + v \in U_1 + U_3 = U_1 + U_2.$$
Therefore, there must exist $w \in U_1$ and $u \in U_2 \subseteq U_3$ such that
$$v = w + u \implies v - u = w.$$
Note that $w \in U_1$ and $v - u \in U_3$, so $w \in U_1 \cap U_3 = U_1 \cap U_2$. Thus $v = u + w$ is a sum of two vectors in $U_2$, which means that $v \in U_2$.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. How do I get to the point where that solution becomes obvious? I am a decent enough abstract thinker but I can't seem to come up with ideas to solve proofs like this one.

Comment: Clearly experience helps a lot. I'm reminded of the proof that, if $U + W = V$ and $U \cap W = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then every $v \in V$ can be uniquely written as a sum of vectors from $u$ and $w$. It uses the intersection criterion in a similar way. I'm also reminded of a particular sum identity involving convex sets that inspired all of my honours thesis. We can't expect either of these things from a student who is just starting out!

Comment: That said, you can basically muddle your way there by looking at the various things you're allowed to assume. You're going to need all of these conditions. I started with a vector in $U_3$, and I had to try to get it into $U_2$ somehow. The intersection condition seemed like an ideal place to start (if I could show $v \in U_1$, then that would immediately imply $v \in U_2$), but it seemed too good to be true, so I went with the sum condition instead. What I'm saying is, it doesn't have to be obvious in order to get there.

Comment: One of the benefits of including some attempts in your questions is that we can incorporate them into your answer. In my experience in tutoring, I find that it looks less like a rabbit is being pulled from a hat when you pay specific reference to what the student has been thinking about the problem. It tends to make the tutoring more effective.

Comment: Hey @CalebCramer, I just realised, I'm your tutor for Maths255, and this is an assignment question. Whoops. :-(